# Discover a website's base timezone before converting to my local time

Tags: javascript, html, developer-tools

Some countries have daylight saving time and others do not, I would like to know if there is any way to find out if a website uses any timezone with daylight saving time or not before it converts the time to my own computer

Site Link:
https://int.soccerway.com/

The closest I found within the site’s HTML was this function but it doesn’t deliver what time zone it uses:

```
      var expires = new Date();
      expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 36500*24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time offset, but it will not tell you anything about whether there is DST is enacted. However, you can get the timezone of the user's browser and then check somewhere (it's step 2) whether the current timezone has DST currently or not:

```js
const timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
console.log(timeZone);
```